# Stitching of captured images to form Panorama

Tags: android, opencv, image-stitching, 360-panorama

i am trying to find something related to photo stitching in order to rotate images in penormic view , but i am not able to find any sample code for this , i have got one **CardBoard sdk** of google , but in that SDk i have not found any sample of stitching images . I even found one library named panoramagl here is it's URL :-

https://github.com/niveuseverto/panoramagl-android

But it again just rotate the pre-defined pnarma image. I just want to know that is there any library present which can provide me the sample of stitching the image and make its panorma.

i even able to found two links but do not know how to use it :-

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_acc269_ty244_yc563/cs4670_final.html

and this :- http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/android-opencv-panorama

but how to use it ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!